# Wordpress substitutes page links with page_id

Tags: wordpress

When I edit a Wordpress page and insert links to pages within my site, the page contents is fine:

```
<a href="http://www.example.org/tutorials/" title="Video Tutorials">  </a>
```

but once I press "Publish" the link is automatically changed to

```
<a href="/?page_id=508" title="Video Tutorials"> </a>
```

On my Wordpress permalink settings I have option

```
http://www.example.org/sample-post/
```

I recently moved my Wordpress site to different domain and updated it to version 4, could this be the reason of its strange behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the permalink options to default settings, saving it and then change it to the settings you originally had?

Comment: @Howlin this does not help